# WinAPI - GetRawInputBuffer

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have problem with GetRawInputBuffer. Code returns no error, but there are no data present in retrieved response.

I have written code according to this [Using GetRawInputBuffer correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866226/using-getrawinputbuffer-correctly)

```
    UINT RawInputSize;
    UINT Result;
    Result = GetRawInputBuffer(NULL, &(RawInputSize), sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
    if (Result == -1)
    {
        DWORD ErrorCode = GetLastError();
        return;
    }

    UINT AllocatedBufferByteCount = RawInputSize * 16;
    RAWINPUT* RawInputBuffer = reinterpret_cast<RAWINPUT*>(malloc(AllocatedBufferByteCount));

    UINT AllocatedBufferByteCountTwo = AllocatedBufferByteCount;
    Result = GetRawInputBuffer(RawInputBuffer, &(AllocatedBufferByteCountTwo), sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
    if (Result == -1)
    {
        DWORD ErrorCode = GetLastError();
        return;
    }

    UINT RawInputCount = Result;

    RAWINPUT* RawInput = RawInputBuffer;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < RawInputCount; ++i)
    {
        switch (RawInput->header.dwType)
        {
            case RIM_TYPEMOUSE:
            {
                this->UpdateMouse(RawInput->data.mouse);
                break;
            }
            case RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD:
            {
                this->UpdateKeyboard(RawInput->data.keyboard);
                break;
            }
        }


        RawInput = NEXTRAWINPUTBLOCK(RawInput); 
    }

    DefRawInputProc(&(RawInputBuffer), RawInputCount, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
```

This code is called outside `case WM_INPUT`. `RawInputCount` is always zero. If I use `GetRawInputData` inside `case WM_INPUT`, I am recieving data correctly.

What is wrong with this code and why are my results empty?

Comment: While I'm sure it seems obvious to you, what's your question? You didn't actually ask one.. :oops:

Comment: @enhzflep Hups...corrected :-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer comes a bit late, but since I had the same problem recently, I'll answer it anyways:
GetRawInputBuffer uses the `WM_INPUT` message to get and buffer the messages. However, you propably uses something like `while(PeekMessage(&Message, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))` to process your window messages, which removes all messages after sent to your application. That way, input messages won't be send to the GetRawInputBuffer method and the method will allways return an size of 0. To solve this problem, you need to use something like this as your main loop:

```
//Process and remove all messages before WM_INPUT
while(PeekMessage(&Message, NULL, 0, WM_INPUT - 1, PM_REMOVE))
{
    TranslateMessage(&Message);
    DispatchMessage(&Message);
}
//Process and remove all messages after WM_INPUT
while(PeekMessage(&Message, NULL, WM_INPUT + 1, (UINT)-1, PM_REMOVE))
{
    TranslateMessage(&Message);
    DispatchMessage(&Message);
}
```

This way, `WM_INPUT` messages are neither processed nor removed by your application, and therefor send to GetRawInputBuffer. Obviusly you could also exchange the `PM_REMOVE` flag with `PM_NOREMOVE`, however this could cause other problems, so I would recommend the above method to process and remove all but the `WM_INPUT` message.

Comment: Your help to me was actually DOUBLED, because in my code I also stupidly forgot to use `while` for the `PeekMessage` and used `if`... I only "peeked" 1 message per frame :D What is the most strange in this situation, is that documentatoin for `GetRawInputBuffer` clearly states this: `Using GetRawInputBuffer, the raw input data is read in the array of variable size RAWINPUT structures and corresponding WM_INPUT messages are removed from the calling thread's message queue.` See? It is supposed to remove it from the queue. However, when I called it before `Peek`, it never removed the messages...

Comment: I actually just checked this with `GetQueueStatus` flag `QS_RAWINPUT`. If I call `GetRawInputBuffer` in a loop and process all inputs before the `while(PeekMessage)`, the QS_RAWINPUT is removed after the `GetRawInputBuffer` calls, as expected. BUT the actual WM_INPUT messages still remain in the queue! Because subsequent `PeekMessage` retrieves and handles them all... This is some total chaos, the way I see it. Documentation only works half-way. Bizarre.